# In VBA, why does putting a textbox value into a cell trigger a for loop in another userform subroutine?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I created an userform with 2 textboxes, 3 buttons and a listbox with two columns. If I click on an entry in the listbox, the list entry which is selected gets transfered to two different textboxes.

**See the code below:**

```
Private Sub NewSourceListBox_Click()

Dim i As Integer

'Show the selected data in the corresponding text boxes
For i = 0 To NewSourceListBox.ListCount - 1
    If NewSourceListBox.Selected(i) Then
        'Hide the add button and show the change button
        NewSourceBtnChange.Top = 168
        NewSourceBtnChange.Visible = True
        NewSourceBtnAdd.Visible = False

        NewSourcesIDTxtBox.Value = NewSourceListBox.List(i, 0)
        NewSourcesSourceTxtBox.Value = NewSourceListBox.List(i, 1)

        'Pass on the selected item row to another subroutine
        selectedItem = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

`selectedItem` is a global variable created in another module, which I need to use in another subroutine. If I change the entries in the text boxes in the userform and click the change button the following code gets executed.

**This code:**

```
Private Sub NewSourceBtnChange_Click()

Dim row As Integer

row = 6257 + selectedItem

'Change the selected data in the list box to the corresponding data in the text boxes
Sheets("Datensätze").Range("A" & row).Value = NewSourcesIDTxtBox.Value
Sheets("Datensätze").Range("B" & row).Value = NewSourcesSourceTxtBox.Value
'Another duplicate entry to make vLookup work
Sheets("Datensätze").Range("C" & row).Value = NewSourcesIDTxtBox.Value

Unload Me
'Unload the new entry user form to repopulate the comboboxes
Unload NewEntryUserForm
NewEntryUserForm.Show

End Sub
```

If I watch this step by step via F8 then the following happens: As soon as  I click the "NewSourceBtnChange" button the corresponding subroutine `NewSourceBtnChange_Click()` starts. When I reach `Sheets("Datensätze").Range("A" & row).Value = NewSourcesIDTxtBox.Value` the program jumps to the `NewSourcesListBox_Click()` routine, executes it two times and jumps back to `Sheets("Datensätze").Range("B" & row).Value = NewSourcesSourceTxtBox.Value`, then executes the `NewSourcesListBox_Click()` routine for another two times and jumps back again to the last entry `Sheets("Datensätze").Range("C" & row).Value = NewSourcesIDTxtBox.Value` and executes the rest of the `NewSourceBtnChange_Click()` routine.

This makes it impossible to get the new data from the text boxes into their destined cells.

**Edit:**

Just to make it easier to reconstruct the described behavior, I exported the userform and its code and [uploaded](https://ufile.io/616yv) it.

Comment: Do you have any `Worksheet_Change` event handlers in the workbook?

Comment: I tried your code and there is no behavior as you have mentioned. It must be related to some other code you already have. As joseph4tw mentioned, `Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_SelectionChange` might be triggering it. Check your code again.

Comment: @joseph4tw and Tehscript. The only thing I have is a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` which repositions the comment boxes into the middle of the visible screen. I commented the whole code block out, but the behavior is still the same. I'll upload the whole userform, maybe this will help to sort things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your code is going through (just the important parts):

**1)** While initializing userform, it populates the listbox with:

`.RowSource = "Datensätze!A6257:B" & 6257 + Sheets("Datensätze").Range("F2").Value - 1`

**2)** When you click listbox item, you trigger `NewSourceListBox_Click` code, populate textboxes with selected items and set item index number to `selectedItem` variable.  (which is handled wrong. You need to declare `selectedItem` as public variable.)

**3)** Then you click `NewSourceBtnChange` which triggers `NewSourceBtnChange_Click`. It sets row number of your selected item:

`row = 6257 + selectedItem`

Then you change this very cell using:

`Sheets("Datensätze").Range("A" & row).Value = NewSourcesIDTxtBox.Value`

which you have used to populate your listbox with:

`.RowSource = "Datensätze!A6257:B" & 6257 + Sheets("Datensätze").Range("F2").Value - 1`

At this moment, listbox is populated again, but this time it has been already selected so it triggers the `NewSourceListBox_Click` code.

Whenever you change the RowSource range, if the listbox is selected, it will behave like this. So you need to deselect the listbox item to workaround this.

**TL;DR:**

After:

```
row = 6257 + selectedItem
```

Insert:

```
NewSourceListBox.Selected(NewSourceListBox.ListIndex) = False
```

Also to be able to get `selectedItem` value in other subs, you need to declare it as public variable. Outside of subs, on the very top, insert:

```
Public selectedItem As Long
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! I didn't think that `Sheets("Datensätze").Range("A" & row).Value = NewSourcesIDTxtBox.Value` would trigger a code block which I thought is only triggered when I first activate the the userform. Now it makes sense why `NewSourceBtnChange` triggers the for loop 2 times (because of the 2 columns) and why the last change doesn't trigger the for loop (because it's not used to populate the list box). This helped really much! Why wouldn't a change to `Userform_Initialize()` work also?